# Reaching into an associated collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model, and event model, and an asset model.

A user can have multiple events.
An event can have multiple assets (images)

Now what I am trying to do is display one (any) event image on a page. Currently I have the following.

Controller

```
@user = current_user  
@events = @user.events
```

View

```
<% @events.each do |e| %>
  <li>
  <% if e.assets.nil? %> 
    <%= image_tag("img36.jpg" , :size => "280x230") %>
  <% else %>
  <%=image_tag e.assets.first.path.url %>   
  <% end %>
  <div class="bar">
  <strong class="heading"><%= e.name %></strong>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="time" title="Time" href="#"><%= e.date %></a></li>
    <li><a class="comments" title="Comments" href="#">53</a></li>
    <li><a class="favourites" title="Favourites" href="#">87</a></li>
    <li><a class="view" title="Views" href="#">242</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <p><%= e.description %><a href="#">more &raquo;</a></p>
 </li>
<% end %>
```

"path"is the string field in the assets table that contains the image path. I'm getting the following error right now.

```
undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you have something returned in assets? maybe it's empty.

Comment: correct, the table is empty, but I thought I'm accounting for that in my if statement. When a user first signs up they won't have any images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when there are no assets associated with an event, the value of `e.assets` will be an empty array, not `nil`. So what is happening is that `e.assets` passes the `nil?` conditional, then you take `e.assets.first` which is `nil` (because the array is empty), and then you try calling `path` on that which obviously doesn't work.

To fix the problem just change:

```
<% if e.assets.nil? %>
```

to:

```
<% if e.assets.empty? %>
```